# Keras Custom Layer with advanced calculations

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to write some custom `Keras` Layers and do some advanced calculations in the layer, for example with Numpy, Scikit, OpenCV...

I know there are some math functions in `keras.backend` that can operate on tensors, but i need some more advanced functions.

However, i have no clue how to implement this correctly, i get the error message:
`You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [...]`

Here is my custom layer:

```py
class MyCustomLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyCustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs):
        """
        How to implement this correctly in Keras?
        """
        nparray = K.eval(inputs)  # <-- does not work
        # do some calculations here with nparray
        # for example with Numpy, Scipy, Scikit, OpenCV...
        result = K.variable(nparray, dtype='float32')
        return result

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        output_shape = tuple([input_shape[0], 256, input_shape[3]])
        return output_shape  # (batch, 256, channels)
```

The error appears here in this dummy model:

```py
inputs = Input(shape=(96, 96, 3))
x = MyCustomLayer()(inputs)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = Dense(1)(x)    
predictions = Activation("sigmoid")(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
```

Thanks for all hints...

Comment: could you provide the code where the error appears please? the error you get is link to the fact that imputs variable is not well define when you call this function. see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10632

Comment: You have to implement those advanced calculations using backend functions (or TensorFlow if that's what you use). There is no work around this as gradients will need to be propagated through your layer. You can't use K.eval either.

Comment: what exactly does this code do? what is your expectation?

Answer (score 1):

**TD;LR You should not mix Numpy inside Keras layers.** Keras uses Tensorflow underneath because it has to track all the computations to be able to compute the gradients in the backward phase.

If you dig in Tensorflow, you will see that it almost covers all the Numpy functionality (or even extends it) and if I remember correctly, Tensorflow functionality can be accessed through the Keras backend (K).

What are the advance calculations/functions you need?

Comment: for example `numpy.histogram`

Comment: I see... I keep on my point. I would try to find the way of programming this function in tensorflow (or the backend of Keras), as bringing data in/out the tensorflow session is costly and then will introduce delays.

Comment: Maybe the `numpy.histogram` could be done in a Keras layer by combining some `keras.backend` functions or Tensorflow functions, for example with `tf.math.round`, `tf.dtypes.cast`, `tf.math.bincount` ... ?

Comment: that's what I mean, yes :D

Answer (score 0):

i think that this kinda process should apply before the model because the process does not contain variables so it cant be optimized.

K.eval(inputs) does not work beacuse you are trying to evaluate a placeholder not variable placeholders has not values for evaluate. if you want get values you should feed it or you can make a list from tensors one by one with tf.unstack()

```
nparray = tf.unstack(tf.unstack(tf.unstack(inputs,96,0),96,0),3,0)
```

your call function is wrong because returns a variable you should return a constant:

```
result = K.constant(nparray, dtype='float32')
return result
```